Navigationbottombar theme is not responding when ThemeMode is changing with provider
I have a navigation bottom bar listening changes in provider. Also I have provider for themeMode changes. I save the changes of theme mode to the hive. When theme mode changes in the application with user click, navigation bottom bar colors are not responding according to the mode of phone. I don't want to change ConsumerWidget to ConsumerStatefulWidget. So how can i change navigation bottom bar colors depend on mode selection?
in main.dart
 themeMode = ref.watch(themeModeNotifierProvider);
 isDark = ref.watch(brightnessModeProvider.notifier).themeIsDark();

theme data
final dark = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  iconTheme: IconThemeData(
    color: themeColor,
  ),
  colorScheme: ColorScheme(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      primary: themeColor,
      onPrimary: themeColor,
      secondary: themeColor,
      onSecondary: themeColor,
      error: appColors.red,
      onError: appColors.red,
      surface: Colors.transparent,
      onSurface: Colors.transparent),
  textTheme: textThemeMedium,
  navigationBarTheme: NavigationBarThemeData(
    iconTheme: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith(
      (states) {
        if (states.contains(WidgetState.selected)) {
          return IconThemeData(color: themeColor);
        }
        return IconThemeData(color: appColors.white);
      },
    ),
    shadowColor: themeColor,
  ),
);

final light = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: appColors.darkGrey),
  colorScheme: ColorScheme(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primary: themeColor,
    onPrimary: themeColor,
    secondary: themeColor,
    onSecondary: themeColor,
    error: appColors.red,
    onError: appColors.red,
    surface: Colors.transparent,
    onSurface: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  textTheme: textThemeMedium,
  navigationBarTheme: NavigationBarThemeData(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    iconTheme: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith(
      (states) {
        if (states.contains(WidgetState.selected)) {
          return IconThemeData(color: themeColor);
        }
        return IconThemeData(color: appColors.darkGrey);
      },
    ),
    shadowColor: themeColor,
  ),
);

navigation bottom bar widget
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    //Go router selected index provider
    final selectedIndex = ref.watch(navigationProviderProvider);

    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      enableFeedback: true,
      currentIndex: selectedIndex,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0.0,
      onTap: (index) {
        ///Go Navigation
      },
      selectedItemColor: themeColor,
      unselectedItemColor: returnColor(),
      items:[_navigationBottomBarItem()],
    );
  }

What i tried;
-adding provider like in main.dart -> nothing changed
-``ìsDark? appColors.white :appColors.darkGrey``` ->also not worked
